# Return statement confusion

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I'm wondering why the return iBiggest does not refer to the iBiggest in the if statement. Is there a way I can make it? My overall objective is to return the row in an array the holds the largest sum. The array is two dimensional.

```
public static int findMaxRow(int[][] arr){

        int curMax=0;
        //int iBiggest;


        for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

            int curSum = 0;

            for (int j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++){


                arr[i][j]+= curSum;

                if (curSum>curMax){
                    curSum=curMax;

                    int iBiggest = i;

                }

              }

            }

        return iBiggest;
        }
```

Comment: Does this compile?  If so, where's the _other_ declaration of `iBiggest`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to broaden the scope of variable, so that is visible from where you want to return it. As you want to return it outside of `for` loop so it should be declared outside:

```
         int iBiggest = 0;
         int curMax=0;


        for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

            int curSum = 0;

            for (int j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++){


                arr[i][j]+= curSum;

                if (curSum>curMax){
                    curSum=curMax;

                    iBiggest = i;

                }

              }

            }

        return iBiggest;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html). There you will learn that you have to declare `iBiggest` outside of the for loop:

```
// function header
{
    int curMax   = 0;
    int iBiggest = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

        int curSum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){

            arr[i][j]+= curSum;

            if (curSum > curMax){
                curSum   = curMax;
                iBiggest = i;
            }
        }
    }
    // Has iBiggest to be declared inside the same scope!
    return iBiggest;
}
```

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for the help and also for the tutorial link!

Comment: You are welcome. Btw. you can accept answers by clicking below the voting buttons if you want. It is a good practice to accept acceptable answers in order to let people know that an answer has solved your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually declare my variables at the top of my method, just so that things like this never happen. You need to have your variable outside of the for, so that the return statement can "see" it. Hope this helps!

```
public static int findMaxRow(int[][] arr){

        int curMax=0;
        int iBiggest = 0;
        int curSum = 0;


        for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

            curSum = 0;

            for (int j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++){


                arr[i][j]+= curSum;

                if (curSum>curMax){
                    curSum=curMax;

                    iBiggest = i;

                }

              }

            }

        return iBiggest;
        }
```